# How can i build my own font-size selection plugin in tinyMCE 4.x?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, tinymce-4

I want to build a `font-size selection plugin` with TinyMce 4 editor. I also want to add `vertical jquery slider` with `input box` so that user can easily change `font-size` or can also able to change manually by adding `font-size` in `input box`.

Anyone has any idea about this how can i build a `plugin` for it???

Please see the attached snap.

SNAP:
[Click Here View Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdCjT.png)

I have tried to add slider like a button but it does not seem to work.

OR

Is there any `plugins` like that which can be installed with `TinyMce`?

Comment: After 6 hrs finally i have done it... i just created plugin. now feeling good..

Comment: please share your code for other users.